# hyperref generates PDF bookmarks for Koma-script document with bookmark option turned off

Tags: hyperref, koma-script

I would like to stop hyperref from creating bookmarks for a KOMA-Script document. The option bookmarks=false does not work with KOMA classes, it works flawlessly with default classes such as report. Is there any way to disable PDF bookmarks in KOMA-Script documents with the hyperref package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Chapter}    
    \section{Section}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KOMA Script loads the `bookmark` package by default, which overrides `hyperref`'s option. You can disable this with the (apparently undocumented) document class option `bookmarkpackage=false`.

Comment: is there something we could easily do in hyperref to make the boolean option work here?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle After some investigation I found the root of the problem (automatic loading of the `bookmark` package). I don't think any modifications are in order (except maybe to the KOMA Script documentation). Maybe a warning would be nice, if `hyperref`'s `bookmarks=false` is used together with `bookmark`.